# Override Prestashop MyAccountController

Tags: overriding, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I try to create override MyAccountController

```
class MyAccountController extends MyAccountControllerCore
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        if ($module = Module::getInstanceByName('my_module')) {
            $urls = $module->getData();

            Tools::redirect($urls['redirect']);
        }
    }
}
```

I saved this file in `override/controllers/front` folder.

After some tests, it does not work. My redirection is not called.

But when I set to true the variable `_PS_DEBUG_PROFILING_`, the redirect is well captured by the profiler.

My Prestashop instance is clean. No modules or files are installed.

Prestashop version : 1.7.8.7

Answer (score 0):

After place your controller in `override`, you need to rebuild the class index.
This is the file:

`var/cache/prod/class_index.php`

Just remove that file, it will be created again, taking in account your override.

Note: `/prod/` because of *production environment*.